# Why does a EditText widget have to be instantiated in fragment onStart method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

While fixing a bug I introduced when manually refactoring, I found that I put this code in the fragment's onCreateView method instead of onStart

```
    EditText et = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.testEditText);
    et.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
        {

            boolean handled = false;

            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
            {
                // Do something.
                handled = true;
            }

            return handled;
        }
    });
```

Having fixed the bug I found myself pondering why the EditText widget is null in onCreateView, and I don't know the answer. I've never really thought about it before, so I googled and checked the manuals but can't find an answer, so can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer has to do with how the `Fragment`'s lifecycle and its hosting `Activity`'s lifecycle line up.

In the code you posted, you're looking for the `EditText` inside the activity:

> ```
> EditText et = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.testEditText);
> ```

This is logically fine, but it relies on two things. First, the activity must exist or `getActivity()` will return null. Second, the activity must have had its `setContentView()` method invoked or `findViewById()` will return null.

Inside the fragment's `onCreateView()`, we know that the activity has already been attached, so the first issue is fine. However, there's no guarantee that the activity's `onCreate()` method will have completed yet, and so there is no guarantee that `setContentView()` was invoked.

The first place within the fragment's lifecycle where its hosting activity is *guaranteed* to have finished executing `onCreate()` is the fragment's `onActivityCreated()` callback. Anything that relies on having a fully "up and running" activity should go here.

Comment: That makes sense, but I thought I checked all the "onX" callbacks, guess I might have missed onActivityCreated(), so I'll give that a try and let you know if it worked, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Yep perfect, I went through all the onX methods before coming here, but I obviously missed that, thanks very much, I can finally delete my fragment's onStart.

Answer (score 0):

Initialising should happen in onCreateView method and not in onStart.

The way you initialise is wrong.

The proper way to initialise in a fragment is :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_layout, parent, false);
    EditText et = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    et.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
    {....}

}
```

Comment: I tried that before, that way produces a null EditText reference. If it makes a difference, I'm using android.support.v4.app.Fragment, compiling API 27, minimum API 19, targeting API 27, running on API 26.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this might be that `onCreateView ()` of the fragement is called before the `onActivityCreated()` the callback the fragment recieves when the `onCreate()` of parent activity returns. Hence the `getActivity()` retuns a null in `onCreateView()` , while works in `onStart()` which is called after the `onActivityCreated()` callback.

Comment: That's sort of the conclusion I came to, which is why I moved the code to onStart, it's just strange that all the TextView widgets are fine in onCreate.

Comment: is your edittext apart of the fragment layout or activity layout?

Comment: Fragment layout, as are all the other widgets.

Comment: Sorry I accepted Ben's answer because it was clearer than yours. In that, it's only after reading Ben's answer that I see that your answer alludes to using onActivityCreated. I wish I could accept both answers.